# Is this casting in golang?

Tags: go, types, type-conversion

`paxPayment, ok = dataObject.(*entities.PassengerPayment)`

What are the brackets used for? I'm not sure what is going on in this assignment operation.

Do you need any more details to answer this question?

Answer (score 184, accepted):

It's a [Type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions). A type assertion can be used to:

- obtain a value of *concrete* type from a value of *interface* type
- or to obtain a value of a *different* interface type than the initial one (an interface with a different [method set](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets), practically not subset of the original one as that could simply be obtained using a simple type [conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions)).

Quoting from the spec:

> For an expression `x` of interface type and a type `T`, the primary expression
>
> ```
> x.(T)
> ```
>
> asserts that `x` is not `nil` and that the value stored in `x` is of type `T`. The notation `x.(T)` is called a *type assertion*.
>
> More precisely, if `T` is not an interface type, `x.(T)` asserts that the dynamic type of `x` is [identical](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_identity) to the type `T`. In this case, `T` must [implement](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets) the (interface) type of `x`; otherwise the type assertion is invalid since it is not possible for `x` to store a value of type `T`. If `T` is an interface type, `x.(T)` asserts that the dynamic type of `x` implements the interface `T`.

More specifically your example is a special form of it which also reports whether the type assertion holds. If not, `ok` will be `false`, and if the assertion holds, `ok` will be `true`.

This special form never panics unlike the form of:

```
paxPayment = dataObject.(*entities.PassengerPayment)
```

Which if `dataObject` does not hold a value of type `*entities.PassengerPayment` will panic.