# Mongo-go-driver get objectID from insert result

Tags: json, mongodb, http, go, mongo-go

After using `InsertOne` to create a new document, when I return the result I'm getting an array of numbers rather than an `ObjectID`. In the DB, the id is generating fine.

```
type User struct {
  ID       string
  Email    string
  Username string
  Password string
}

var db = ...

// UserStore creates user
func UserStore(c echo.Context) (err error) {

  coll := db.Collection("users")

  u := new(User)
  if err = c.Bind(u); err != nil {
    return c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, err)
  }

  result, err := coll.InsertOne(
    context.Background(),
    bson.NewDocument(
        bson.EC.String("email", u.Email),
        bson.EC.String("username", u.Username),
        bson.EC.String("password", u.Password),
    ),
  )
  if err != nil {
    return c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, err)
  }

  return c.JSON(http.StatusCreated, result)
}
```

This returns something like `InsertedID: [90, 217, 85, 109, 184, 249, 162, 204, 249, 103, 214, 121]` instead of a normal `ObjectID`. How can I return the actual `ObjectID` from the newly inserted document?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

A successful [`Collection.InsertOne()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/mongo#Collection.InsertOne) will return a result of type [`mongo.InsertOneResult`](https://godoc.org/github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/mongo#InsertOneResult), which is a struct wrapping the ID of the newly inserted document:

```
type InsertOneResult struct {
    // The identifier that was inserted.
    InsertedID interface{}
}
```

The official MongoDB Go driver uses the [`primitive.ObjectID`](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive#ObjectID) type to represent MongoDB ObjectIds. This type is a simple byte array:

```
type ObjectID [12]byte
```

To access this type you need to import the [primitive package](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive).

```
import "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive"
```

`InsertOneResult.InsertedID` will hold a dynamic type of `primitive.ObjectID`. The `primitive.ObjectID` type does not define a custom JSON marshaling method (does not implement [`json.Marshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshaler)), which means when the result is converted to JSON, the default marshaling rules will be used, which for a byte array (not slice) is what you see: the decimal representation of the bytes of the ObjectID.

You should not convert a value of type `InsertOneResult` to JSON, as it  (or rather `primitive.ObjectID` itself) is not "JSON-friendly" (at least not in the current version).

Instead create / wrap your own type where you define how you want the result to look like in JSON, for example:

```
if oid, ok := result.InsertedID.(primitive.ObjectID); ok {
    return c.JSON(http.StatusCreated, map[string]interface{}{
        "id": oid.String(),
    })
} else {
    // Not objectid.ObjectID, do what you want
}
```

The above code would result in a JSON response like this:

```
{"id":"ObjectID(\"5ad9a913478c26d220afb681\")"}
```

Or if you just want the hex representation:

```
if oid, ok := result.InsertedID.(primitive.ObjectID); ok {
    return c.JSON(http.StatusCreated, map[string]interface{}{
        "id": oid.Hex(),
    })
}
```

Which would be:

```
{"id":"5ad9a913478c26d220afb681"}
```

Comment: Great answer! But now things have changed and instead of using `objectid.ObjectID` you need to use [primitive.ObjectID](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive#ObjectID)

Comment: @AdamD Yes, you're right. Answer was created prior to `primitive.ObjectID`.

Comment: the answer is correct and for getting `objectid` you can user primitive.`primitive.ObjectIDFromHex("your generated hex")` which will return `ibjectid` instead of hex-decimal string presentation.

Comment: new to golang. I don't exactly understand when you said `result.InsertedID.(primitive.ObjectID)` what are you doing here. `InsertedID` is empty interface, so...

Comment: @Tannu It's a type assertion, see [Is this casting in golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31379404/is-this-casting-in-golang/31379484#31379484)